# How to Fill arraylist from imported file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a program that needs to put the imported file into an arraylist and break it apart to look like:

```
00000000    100 80  100 20  20  40  50
12345687    98  67  88  20  19  37  39
89763465    67  79  90  18  16  35  44
```

I want to read the first numbers as one list and so on.

```
public void studentData() throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");
    String filename = scanner.nextLine().trim();

    filename.equalsIgnoreCase(filename);
    File f = new File(filename);
    Scanner file = new Scanner(f);
    String fileText = file.nextLine();

    while (file.hasNext()){
        list.add(file.next());
    }
    file.close();
```

It is printing out absolutely nothing. I would appreciate positive feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println("file has next")` in your while? I'm not sure it's being reached. If you add a print you will see if that code is executed

Comment: It's not printing: "Enter a file name: "?

Comment: There's no point in this line `filename.equalsIgnoreCase(filename);`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ was just about to point that out. What in god's name is that there for

Comment: it might be a file permission issue ? also, can you show us the raw file contents ? and how you're trying to output the data ? the only output you're supposed to see with this code is "Enter a file name: "

Comment: It is reaching the while loop and it prints it out like 100 times.

Comment: If it's not permission issues then you might be not finding the file, it could be in a different directory, so can you also show us the content of `String filename` ?

Comment: @Cruncher In the name of Walhalla  ;)

Comment: @CBH man, you said it prints absolutelly nothing, now you say it prints 100 times. If it prints 100 times, what's the problem? You only have 100 rows in your file.

Comment: `It is printing out absolutely nothing.` is turning out to be the most misleading post I've seem

Comment: Okay well thats what was happening

Comment: He said to have it print "file has next" and that is what printed a hundred time, not the file itself

Comment: So you're calling `studentData()` 100 times?

Comment: It prints nothing because you don't ask it to print anything. Also, you seem to be putting each line into the list, instead of breaking the lines into the individual numbers within them.

Comment: @CBH It would help to know if you want to read the file line by line or number by number, i.e. what should `list` contain?

Comment: @tmh It should read the header of the file together, then it should read each number separately, as in the 000000000, and so on are the student numbers and the following number in the line are the grades received on those particular assignments, i.e. student 12345687 got 98/100 and 69/80 and so on

Answer (score 0):

your code is working,

few moments :

if your file doesn't start with `\n`
then remove

```
 String fileText = file.nextLine();
```

and add this :

```
for (String string : list) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

at the end, to output your values.

Comment: If I do this it doesnt print anything

Comment: @CBH I'm 99% sure that your method fires maybe a `FileNotFoundException`, but you have it in a `try-catch` with an empty `catch` block so you don't see the exception being thrown... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to read the first numbers as one list and so on.

you can store every line of numbers in the list you defined it like this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");
    String filename = scanner.nextLine().trim();

    filename.equalsIgnoreCase(filename); // dose't do anything?!!!!
    File f = new File(filename);
    Scanner file = new Scanner(f);
    //String fileText = file.nextLine(); this line removed the first line of txt

    while (file.hasNext()) {
        list.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(file.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D+",",").split(",")))); // this line is what you need
    }
    file.close();
```

i hope that's your needs